# Django : Mezzanine front search module

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, django-modeltranslation

I'm having a problem in my django's app using [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/).

I have specified models searchable this way :

```
SEARCH_MODEL_CHOICES = ('organization-pages.CustomPage',
                        'organization-network.DepartmentPage',
                        'organization-network.TeamPage',
                        'organization-network.Person',
                        'organization-projects.ProjectTopicPage',
                        'pages.Page',
                        'organization-media.Playlist',
                        'mezzanine_agenda.Event',
                        'organization-projects.Project',
                        'shop.Product',
                        'organization-magazine.Article')

PAGES_MODELS = ('organization-pages.CustomPage',
                'organization-magazine.Topic',
                'organization-network.DepartmentPage',
                'organization-network.TeamPage',
                'organization-projects.ProjectTopicPage',
                'shop.Product')

SEARCH_PARENTS_MODELS = ('organization-network.Person',)
```

And i haven't touched any of Mezzanine's source code.

I'm using django model-translation, having a object like that :

```
d = DepartementPage.objects.create()
d.title_fr = 'french'
d.title_en = 'english'
```

If i try to search it with Mezzanine's search engine, i'll only find it if i input the title of the language i'm currently using.

I mean if i'm using application in english, i'll not get my object searching 'french', while it [should do](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/search-engine.html)

Do you know where my issue comes from ?

Comment: What `search_fields` have you defined on your `DepartementPage` model? Those determine which fields are searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the model you have specified in your code above:

```
d = DepartementPage.objects.create()
d.title_fr = 'french'
d.title_en = 'english'
```

You should be able to successfully search the fields by using the following in your `views.py`:

```
query = "search string"
search_fields = ("title_fr", "title_en")
results = DepartementPage.objects.search(query, search_fields=search_fields)
```

From the [docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/search-engine.html):

> If `search_fields` is not provided in the call to `search`, the fields used will be the default fields specified for the model.

You haven't posted the rest of your model fields, but I assume you also have the default `title` field (and `title_fr`, `title_en` are being generated automatically by the `django-modeltranslation` app). The `title` field is the default, and so will be the only field included in the search results. Good luck!